# Connect to IBM MQ (on-perm) from AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ibm-mq, pymqi

Has anyone tried publishing a message to IBM MQ (hosted on-perm) from AWS Lambda (Python)? I just wanted to check if it is possible and if there is a recommended approach, please let me know.